# Web.config Custom Configuration Section in single external file, Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, configuration, web-config

I have a couple custom configuration sections defined in my projects web.config, with the current web.config setup these are referenced with no problem.  I am now trying to extract some of these custom configuration sections along with appSettings entries to their own .config file because the values are changing from environment (DEV, QA, UAT, PROD).

The problems I am coming across is that if I have my custom configuration sections pointing to the same file they each expect the root element to be that type.  Below is an snippet of an attempted web.config setup.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="custom1" type="Namespace.custom1, myProject"/>
        <section name="custom2" type="Namespace.custom2, myProject"/>
    </configSections>
    <custom1 file="/Dev.config">
    </custom1>
    <custom2 file="/Dev.config">
    </custom2>

    <appSettings file="/Dev.config">
    ... non environment specific entries
    </appSettings>

</configuration>
```

Inside of my Dev.config file I have the following sections

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <custom1>
        <customVal1 attr1="abc" attr2="xyz"/>
    </custom1>
    <custom2>
        <diffCustomVal1 difAttr1="True" difAttr2="Jim"/>
    </custom2>

    <appSettings>
        ... environment specific entries
    </appSettings>
```

I've looked online but haven't found any ideas that I liked.  I was wondering how other people approached this problem.  I have also tried creating a singular external config from a different custom configuration section putting the ones shown above inside of that file but then the program wasn't able to pull appSettings entries from that config file.

Answer (score 0):

From a continuous delivery point of view, it would be more straight-forward to simply have separate config files for each environment.

They can be kept in a separate folder in source, with the 'DEV' one being the default one kept with the project.

You would control which config file gets deployed to each environment as part of the deployment scripts/process.

I have seen the kind of 'chaining' you are talking about before, and the end result has usually been labyrinthine config with masses of redundant entries ending up in each environment.

Comment: This is certainly an option but I feel like if done well with only a single external reference you get the best of both worlds.  It also makes it easier to track what is changing from environment to environment when your just looking at a subset rather than the entire file.